# How does the for each loop works with lisbox.items(0)?

Tags: vb.net

```
    cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [OrderDetail] ([OrderID],[CinemaID], [SeatID], [MovieName],[MovieTime],[Price]) VALUES (@OrderID,@CinemaID, @SeatID,@MovieName,@MovieTime,@Price)", con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrderID", dbase.OleDbType.Numeric, 15).Value = Label11.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CinemaID", dbase.OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = Movie.CinID
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SeatID", dbase.OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = ListBox1.Items(0)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MovieName", dbase.OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = Movie.MovieN
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MovieTime", dbase.OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = Movie.MovieT

    Dim Sql As String
    Dim data As dbase.OleDbDataReader
    Dim cmdd As dbase.OleDbCommand
    Sql = "select * from SeatType where ID = """ & SID & """"
    cmdd = New dbase.OleDbCommand(Sql, con)
    con.Open()
    data = cmdd.ExecuteReader
    data.Read()
    SPrice = data("Price")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price", dbase.OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = SPrice
    con.Close()

    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Saved")
    con.Close()
```

I want this whole thing to go through the for each loop, so the `listbox1.items(0)` just keep on changing depending on the items index.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I think you need to explain what the SQL query has to do with the list box?

Comment: @Enigmativity, The listbox contain a seatID, which need to be saved in seperatly row, when inserting it will contain all the same information just different listbox items.

Comment: So you want to insert a new record for each seat ID in the list box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this doing what you need?

```
For Each seatID in ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String)()
    cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [OrderDetail] ([OrderID],[CinemaID], [SeatID], [MovieName],[MovieTime],[Price]) VALUES (@OrderID,@CinemaID, @SeatID,@MovieName,@MovieTime,@Price)", con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrderID", dbase.OleDbType.Numeric, 15).Value = Label11.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CinemaID", dbase.OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = Movie.CinID
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SeatID", dbase.OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = seatID
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MovieName", dbase.OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = Movie.MovieN
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MovieTime", dbase.OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = Movie.MovieT

    'Remainder of your code
Next
```

Comment: @Ruby - If this is what you want then please select this answer by clicking the big tick. Also up-vote too if you think this is a good Answer.